# Objects array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

are there any way to create an object form any class inside a numpy array?. Something like:

```
a = zeros(4)

for i in range(4):
   a[i]=Register()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
a = numpy.array([Register() for _ in range(4)])
```

Here, `a.dtype` is `dtype('object')`.

Alternatively, if you really need to reserve memory for your array and then build it element by element, you can do:

```
a = numpy.empty(shape=(4,), dtype=object)
a[0] = Register()  # etc.
```

Comment: @Mike: thank you for spotting the typo in the first solution; what I meant was of course what you put in your solution.  I had forgotten to build the list first; it's now corrected.  For the second solution, I switched to numpy.empty.

Answer (score 5):

The items in numpy arrays are statically typed, and when you call `zeros` you make an array of floats. To store arbitrary Python objects, use code like

```
numpy.array([Register() for i in range(4)])
```

which makes an array with `dtype=object`, which you could also specify manually.

Consider whether you really want numpy in this case. I don't know how close this example is to your use case, but oftentimes a numpy array of dtype object, especially a one-dimensional one, would work at least as well as a list.