# numpy array of python objects

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy

Since when did numpy allow you to define an array of python objects? [Objects array with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674139/objects-array-with-numpy).

<strike>Is there any fundamental difference between these arrays and a python list?</strike>

What is the difference between these arrays and say, a python tuple?

There are several handy numpy functions I would like to use, i.e. masks and element-wise operations, on an array of python objects and I would like to use them in my analysis, but I'm worried about using a feature I can't find documentation for anywhere. Is there any documentation for this 'object' datatype?

Was this feature was added in preparation for merging numpy into the standard library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "fundamental" difference is that a Numpy `array` is fixed-size, while a Python `list` is a [dynamic array](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Dynamic_array).

```
>>> class Foo:
...  pass
... 
>>> x = numpy.array([Foo(), Foo()])
>>> x.append(Foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

(You can get around this with `numpy.concatenate`, but still Numpy arrays aren't meant as a drop-in replacement for `list`.)

Arrays of `object` are perfectly well [documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), but be aware that you'll have to pass `dtype=object` sometimes:

```
>>> numpy.array(['hello', 'world!'])
array(['hello', 'world!'], 
      dtype='|S6')
>>> numpy.array(['hello', 'world!'], dtype=object)
array(['hello', 'world!'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: More of the object arrays here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html  They have been a part of Numpy since the beginning.

Comment: Is there a difference in performance? Is it possible to do vectorized computation in C with object arrays like those for numeric arrays?