# Python: Differences between lists and numpy array of objects

Tags: python, numpy

What are the advantages and disadvantages of storing Python objects in a `numpy.array` with `dtype='o'` versus using `list` (or `list` of `list`, etc., in higher dimensions)?

Are numpy arrays more efficient in this case?  (It seems that they cannot avoid the indirection, but might be more efficient in the multidimensional case.)

Comment: I personally have never come across compelling uses for NumPy arrays of *objects*. It would be interesting to see if someone can come up with a convincing example. (+1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141853/numpy-array-of-python-objects

Comment: @NPE I mostly agree, other than as a convenient way to do (some) mathematical operations with arrays of `Fraction` objects (or the like), without resorting to half a dozen nested `zip`'s and `map`'s.

Comment: @NPE [NodePy](http://numerics.kaust.edu.sa/nodepy/) uses NumPy arrays of objects (sympy expressions) to do some exact analysis of numerical methods for ODEs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Slicing works differently with NumPy arrays. [The NumPy docs devote a lengthy page on the topic.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)  To highlight some points:

- NumPy slices can slice through multiple dimensions
- All arrays generated by NumPy basic slicing are always views of the original array, while slices of lists are shallow copies.
- You can assign a scalar into a NumPy slice.
- You can insert and delete items in a `list` by assigning a sequence of different length to a slice, whereas NumPy would raise an error.

Demo:

```
>>> a = np.arange(4, dtype=object).reshape((2,2))
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]], dtype=object)
>>> a[:,0]             #multidimensional slicing
array([0, 2], dtype=object)
>>> b = a[:,0]
>>> b[:] = True        #can assign scalar
>>> a                  #contents of a changed because b is a view to a
array([[True, 1],
       [True, 3]], dtype=object)
```

Also, NumPy arrays provide convenient mathematical operations with arrays of objects that support them (e.g. `fraction.Fraction`).

Comment: Also, you can use numpy helpers like `flat`, `flatten`, `nditer`

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is less memory use than a Python list. Also Numpy is faster and more convenient than a list.

For example: if you want to add two lists in Python you have to do looping over all element in the list. On the other hand in Numpy you just add them.

```
# adding two lists in python
sum = []
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [2, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(l1)):
   print sum.append(l1[i]+l2[i])
# adding in numpy
a1 = np.arange(3)
a2 = np.arange(3)
sum2 = a1+a2
print sum2
```

Comment: I wasn't asking about arrays of numbers.  I was asking about arrays of objects.  And I don't know that Python lists need more memory or are slower.  After all, they're both just contiguous arrays underneath.