# {OverflowError} Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Getting the below error

```
{OverflowError}Python int too large to convert to C long
```

when running.

```
EN_Users.objects.get(id=1) # EN_User --> Model | id--> primary key
```

Any help to fix this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check here for issue cause: ["OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" on windows but not mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma)

If possible, you should be able to correct it by removing the int casting and sticking to default float.