# How to load/covert pandas dataframe with string values into pytorch dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I am working on windows machine.
I am trying to load pandas dataframe which has one columns as text(string) and another column as label (int). I want to load this dataframe into pytorch dataset.
Let's say above data is in dataframe df.

I am using below

```
train_target = torch.DoubleTensor(df['Text'].values)
```

I also used below to load directly from csv file.

```
TEXT1 = data.Field(tokenize = 'spacy', include_lengths = True)
LABEL1 = data.LabelField(dtype = torch.float)
fields = [('text',TEXT1),(label,LABEL1)]
train_data, valid_data, test_data = data.TabularDataset.splits(
                                        path = '.',
                                        train = '1.csv',
                                        validation = '1.csv',
                                        test = '1.csv',
                                        format = 'csv',
                                        fields = fields,
                                        skip_header = True
)
```

But it is giving error as

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I am searching for such text conversion into pytorch,tensor object .

Comment: Do you have numbers larger than `sys.maxsize` in `LABEL1`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma

Comment: Also, please post the top 10 lines of your csv here.

Comment: The problem is with TEXT1 . I believe while collecting text data it is not able to understand it (strings) , as tensors know only int,float,bool etc.

My csv contains only below lines 

```Text Label
My Name is rahul 0
My name is julia 1
```

Comment: How can I directly use pandas dataframes (train, validation, test) for torch, and process them for deep learning (change each to text, label fields, and build vocab)?