# Python Problem: "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long"

Tags: python, sympy

```
import sympy as sy
x = sy.symbols('x')
def f2(x,t,l):
    return 5*sy.log(x)+14388/((273+t)*x)-sy.log((1.1910*10**8)/l+1)
print(sy.solve(f2(x,35,80),x))
```

Result is:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: python 2, 64-bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma

Comment: In Py3, your calculation results in a crash (`isympy` session `killed`).  Even when I try to scale down the constants.  What sort of solution do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your equation. There does not appear to be a solution:

```
>>> eq=f2(x,35,80);eq
5*log(x) - 14.2134480713559 + 327/(7*x)
```

There is a minimum in the function and it is convex up at that point and positive:

```
>>> solve(eq.diff(x))
[327/35]
>>> eq.subs(x,_[0]).n()
1.95961247568333
>>> eq.diff(x,2).subs(x,Rational(327,35))
6125/106929
```

So if the constant were a little more negative, everything would work:

```
>>> eq.subs(eq.atoms(Float).pop(),-20)
5*log(x) - 20 + 327/(7*x)
>>> ans=solve(_)
>>> [i.n(2) for i in ans]
[44., 3.3]
```