# unable to print list(range(4**4**4)) in Python 3

Tags: python, list, range, overflow

Can someone please help explain why I am unable to print

```
>>> list(range(4**4**4)).
```

I am receiving an error OverflowError: range() result has too many items

Comment: Because that's a huge number?

Comment: Yes I understand but what is the limit for list(range())?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*, here?

Comment: I am trying to understand the computational effect of calling a list on an element of range type

Comment: ...it builds a list of all of the numbers in the range.

Comment: I understand, but once I received the error I was curious to understand why does this happen though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892204/unable-to-print-listrange444-in-python-3?noredirect=1#comment104049697_58892204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize

> sys.maxsize The largest positive integer supported by the platform’s
>   Py_ssize_t type, and thus the maximum size lists, strings, dicts, and
>   many other containers can have.

Try this code to check whether you would be able to create list of your size:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize > 4**4**4
```

and try this to verify how python resolves powers in your case:

```
>>> print(2**2**3)
256
>>> print(2**(2**3))
256
>>> print((2**2)**3)
64
```

Answer (score 0):

- You will get an OverflowError if the list has more elements than can be fit into a signed long:

  - On 32bit Python: 2**31 - 1
  - On 64 bit Python: 2**63 - 1
  - You can get a MemoryError even for values just under that.

  For example your number is very big:

  - 2**64 = 18446744073709551616
  - 4**4**4 = 13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096