# Python int too large to convert to C int

Tags: python, int

Before you mark me as a duplicate, [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma) are about Python ints being too long too convert into C *long*s, not C ints. When I try and do this:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000000)
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000000)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int
```

is there any way to surpass this, or override it?

Comment: There's no point having a recursion limit if you allow it to get anywhere close to C's max int. I once had a justifiable reason to set it at 2000 in a DP algorithm, but otherwise I wouldn't mess with it. XY-problem? You may want to look at using a data structure; there may be some duplicates here.

Comment: I know. I was just curious, because I've run in to similar errors before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The variable is the type that it is. You can't set it to a value bigger than what it can hold. You'll have to live with a recursion depth of a mere two billion and change, instead of ten billion; I suspect you'll run out of memory before you get that many call frames deep anyway.

Comment: Yes, my shell restarted partway through