# Why is Python (int) too large for C in my OpenCV Lane Detection?

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error, overflow

The below code is for a lane detection algo, I have used Canny Edge detection to work the follow code. However, there are a few errors that I am facing if you could check and let me know it would be of great help.
I feel the errors are somewhere around the various arguments and parameters in Python since I might not entirely be thorough with the maths of the problem.

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
#108 300
def empty(a) :
pass

```
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.resizeWindow('image',640,240)

#---track-bars

cv2.createTrackbar('MIN-VAL','image', 0, 300, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('MAX-VAL','image',0, 300, empty)

# while True:





def ROI1(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    triangle = np.array([
        [(200, height), (1150, height), (700, 400)]
    ])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, triangle, 255)
    return mask

def ROI2(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    triangle = np.array([
        [(0, 650), (1050, height), (750, 445)]
    ])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, triangle, 255)
    return mask

def avergaeLines(image, linez):
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []

    for line in linez:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
        parameters = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
        slope = parameters[0]
        intercept = parameters[1]
        if slope < 0:
             left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
        else:
            right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    left_Fit_Average = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    right_Fit_Average = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    left_line = coord(image, left_Fit_Average)
    right_line = coord(image, right_Fit_Average)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])

def displayLines(image, lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)
    return line_image

def coord(image, linePara):
    try:
        slope, intercept = linePara
    except TypeError:
        slope, intercept = 0.001, 0
    y1 = image.shape[0]
    y2 = int(y1*(4/5))
    x1 = int((y1 - intercept)/slope)
    x2 = int((y2-intercept)/slope)
    return np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("challenge_video.mp4")



#img = cv2.imread("test3.jpg")




while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    while True:
        lane_image = np.copy(img)
        # cv2.imshow("a", lane_image)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(lane_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        # cv2.imshow("b", gray)
        blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
        # cv2.imshow("c", blur_gray)
        min_val = cv2.getTrackbarPos('MIN-VAL', 'image')
        max_val = cv2.getTrackbarPos('MAX-VAL', 'image')
        canny_blur_gray = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, 0, 159)
        # cv2.imshow("f", canny_blur_gray)
        mask = ROI2(canny_blur_gray)
        ADDED = cv2.bitwise_and(canny_blur_gray, mask)
        lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(ADDED, 2, np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=70, maxLineGap=4)
        #70 AND 7 WORKS FINE
        averagedLines = avergaeLines(lane_image, lines)
        linesImage = displayLines(lane_image, averagedLines)
        comboImage = cv2.addWeighted(lane_image, 0.8, linesImage, 1, 1)
        key = cv2.waitKey(100)
        cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

        cv2.imshow("RESULT", comboImage)
        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('c'):
            break





        #188 but 209 seems perfect
    # print(min_wal, max_val)
    #ROI_image = ROI(canny_blur_gray)
```

Below are the various errors that come -

```
packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:380: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
avg = a.mean(axis)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
Traceback (most recent call last):
     
linesImage = displayLines(lane_image, averagedLines)
in displayLines
cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

https://youtu.be/LfnBPeoyGBg

https://youtu.be/SCXg2fDbkCg

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" on windows but not mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma)

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous hey, it does but since my code is a little vast your solution doesn't allow me to understand the exact source of my error. it would be better if someone provided the source error.

Answer (score 0):

You need the array elements to have a larger data type, like double. Try this. I think that would be enough:

```
line_image = np.zeros_like(image,dtype=np.longdouble)
```

Comment: hi, @Andrewgmz well i might sound like an absolute beginner here, however, this is the error that springs up when i try making the change you suggested. `cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'`

Comment: What happens is that you can do operations like multiply images, add etc. with a floating data type, double or other to get better precision. However, the format of the images is integer 8bits, so whenever you use OpenCV functions you must always cast to integer. Sorry, I forgot that detail. Could you attach the images that you are using, so I can better see the type of data that the displayLines function generates.

Comment: sure, i am editing the document with the videos

Comment: the links been attahed to the original post can u have a look?

Comment: I need the video "challenge_video.mp4" to test the code on my own

Comment: its attached do have a look again?