# How to convert numpy array of floats with arbitrary precision (dtype=object) to array of integers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of floats of arbitrary precision (dtype=object).
How do I convert this array of floats with arbitrary precision to
array of integers?
a = np.array([10662878767676765765756765768768787987, 1068768988765462575276572656879287982,..], dtype= object)
b = a*821627.1218279279222972
a = b.astype(int)
How do I round off b to get back array of integers without losing precision?

np.astype gives me the following error:

Overflowerror: Python int too large to convert to C long.

Thanks much for the help!

Comment: What do you actually mean by "floats of arbitrary precision"? Standard Python `float` is fixed-precision, as is anything floating-point in NumPy.

Comment: Do you want round or floor the items of the array?

Comment: "I have a numpy array of floats of arbitrary precision (dtype=object)." what does that mean? That seem contradictory.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38314118/3216427

Comment: Using `np.int64` will allow for larger ints, but note that, as far as I know, NumPy won't let you have truly arbitrary precision ints. Using 64 bit ints moves the limit a lot higher, but there will still be a limit.

Answer (score -1):

The error arises when the size of the integer exceeds the maximum python int size (See [article](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/)).  If you are trying `.astype(dtype=int)`, try using `.astype(dtype=np.int64)` instead.  NOTE:  Still there is an upper limit!

#### With "int"

```py
A = np.array([1.3, 3.5, 0.2545345345345, 2354234235], dtype=object)
A.astype(dtype=int)

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

#### With "np.int64

```py
A.astype(dtype=np.int64)

> array([         1,          3,          0, 2354234235], dtype=int64)
```

#### The max int size in python is 2147483647

*Values less than or equal to the max*

```py
A = np.array([2147483647], dtype=object)
A.astype(dtype=int)

> array([2147483647])
```

*Values greater than the max*

```py
A = np.array([2147483647 + 1], dtype=object)
A.astype(dtype=int)

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: "The error arises when the size of the integer exceeds sys.maxsize" no? What does `sys.maxsize` have to do with this?

Comment: This is a great answer, with just one detail: `sys.maxsize` is about pointer sizes for your hardware.  I'm not sure it's about `int` size.

Comment: On my machine, `sys.maxsize` is 9223372036854775807, but ìnt` overflows on your example of 2354234235.

Comment: @joanis, good call.  Let me revise the Answer.

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize for the official definition of `sys.maxsize`.

Comment: Your article link is old 2015, and seems to be written from a Py 2 view point.  In Py3, there isn't a (formal) distinction between Python `int` and `long int`.  `sys.maxsize` gives the largest 64 bit int value, matching the `numpy` `int64` dtype.  For `y=np.array(sys.maxsize)`, `y+1` is a negaive, wrapped around.  `y.item()+1 is a Python int, and does not wrap around.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I don't see where where `sys.maxsize` is in my Answer?

Comment: You mentioned a "maximum integer size". There is none (ok, theoretically you will run out of address space, and practically, you'll run out of memory)

Comment: Your comment was "sys.maxsize has nothing to do with any of this. Just remove it."  So my question is where do you see `sys.maxsize`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, without any justification for why the link & explanation are "totally wrong", I can't really address your concern.  However, the linked article is explaining the behavior that I am demonstrating with the output of the code in my Answer.  Specifically, the article states, "When the result of an operation would fall outside this range, the result is normally returned as a long integer (in some cases, the exception OverflowError is raised instead). "  This is exactly what I am seeing when the value exceeds the upper limit stated in the article (2147483647).