# Handling attributes of a class within a numpy array

Tags: python, class, numpy, attributes

I would like to handle class attributes **without going through a Python for loop**. To handle large arrays, numpy is the best/fastest but is it possible to access class attributes within a numpy array? Consider the following simplistic code:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar1 = 10
        self.myvar2 = 20

myarray1 = np.arange(0, 1000, 1)
myarray2 = np.array([MyClass() for i in range(1000)])
```

All the values of `myarray1` would be easily modifiable through one line:

```
myarray1 += 5
```

But how can I access `myvar1` of all of the `MyClass` instances in `myarray2` and modify it in one go? (is it even possible?) I know that the following does not work but it gives the idea of what I want to achieve:

```
myarray2.myvar1 += 5
myarray2[myarray2.myvar1] += 5
```

I have been looking around a lot to find a solution and the closest thing I could find is numpy's recarray that can kind of mimic Python classes, but it does not seem to be a solution for me as the class I am using is a subclass (a pyglet Sprite to be exact) so I do need to use a Python class.

### Edit

Following up on hpaulj comment, I am trying to use a vectorized function of the class to update its attribute. Is it an efficient way of updating all the instances of the class?

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar1 = 10
        self.myvar2 = 20
    def modifyvar(self):
        self.myvar1 += 5
        return self

vecfunc = np.vectorize(MyClass.modifyvar)
myarray2 = np.array([MyClass() for i in range(1000)])
myarray2 = vecfunc(myarray2)
```

However, another problem arises: when use this code, `myarray2[0].myvar1` returns 20 instead of 15! `myarray2[1].myvar1` does return 15, same goes for the rest of the array. Why is `myarray2[0]` different here?

---

### Solution

Vectorizing a function of the class allows handling the attribute of several of its instances without a for loop. The code of the solution:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar1 = 10
        self.myvar2 = 20
    def modifyvar(self):
        self.myvar1 += 5
        return self

vecfunc = np.vectorize(MyClass.modifyvar, otypes=[object])
myarray2 = np.array([MyClass() for i in range(1000)])
vecfunc(myarray2)
```

Note: add `otype=[object]` when using vectorize and dealing with objects.

Comment: Is the only reason that you want to avoid a for loop because you hope/expect it to be faster without one?

Comment: It is one of the main reasons but, even if it does not improve performance,  I would still like to know if it is possible to access attributes of an object within a numpy array.

Comment: `myarray2` has `dtype=object`.  So each entry in its data buffer is a pointer to an instance elsewhere in memory.  The vectorized (using compiled code) operations for that type of array are quite rudimentary.

Comment: `recarray` is an overlay on structured arrays.  The data is stored as constant size 'tuples' (as opposed to numbers or pointers).  With a structured array you could use `myarray3['myvar1'] +=1`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't see how a `recarray` could update all of the python class instances at once, could you explain a bit? For vectorized operations, please see my edit and let me know if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objects array with numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674139/objects-array-with-numpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra application of `modifyvar` to the 1st element results from `vectorize` trying to determine the type of array to return.  Specifying the `otypes` gets around that problem:

```
vecfunc = np.vectorize(MyClass.modifyvar,otypes=[object])
```

With this 'inplace' modifier, you don't need to pay attention to what is returned:

```
vecfunc(myarray2)
```

is sufficient.

From the `vectorize` documentation:

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling
>   the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided
>   by specifying the `otypes` argument.

If you defined an `add5` method like:

```
    def add5(self):
        self.myvar1 += 5
        return self.myvar1
```

then

```
vecfunc = np.vectorize(MyClass.add5,otypes=[int])
vecfunc(myarray2)
```

would return a numeric array, and modify `myarray2` at the same time:

```
array([15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15])
```

to display the values I use:

```
[x.myvar1 for x in myarray2]
```

I really should define a vectorized 'print'.

This looks like one of the better applications of `vectorize`.  It doesn't give you any compiled speed, but it does let you use the array notation and broadcasting while operating on your instances one by one.  For example `vecfunc(myarray2.reshape(2,5))` returns a `(2,5)` array of values.

Comment: Very nice! It works and the performance is greatly improved when compared to using a for loop. Thank you :)

Comment: Might have overstated it for the performance, needs further testing. But it is still a nice way to handle classes

Comment: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Obarray - suggestion to store instance attributes in a record array, and create instances on the fly to access methods.